# mysql query on json data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a param field in my mysql table what's contains json data.
After encode looks like this:

```
  'config.enable_comments' => string '1' 
  'metadata.description' => string '' 
  'metadata.keywords' => string '' 
  'metadata.robots' => string '' 
  'metadata.author' => string '' 
  'config.primary_category' => string '157'
```

how can i make a mysql query depending for example on config.primary_category.

```
SELECT params
FROM #__zoo_item
WHERE  config.primary_category = ". $id;
```

Comment: thats a bad idea to store it as json. you really should normalize your database.

Comment: If it isn't too late to change this to a proper normalization scheme, you absolutely should change it. This is going to cause you lots and lots of headaches...

Comment: the thing is that this one is a joomla component(purchased) what is storing some params as json and I would like to trigger out some items where config.primary.category is equivalent with id. I'm not a professional maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Safest thing is to retrieve the json string, json_decode it back to a native PHP structure, and work with that. About all you can inside MySQL is string operations, and you're not VERY careful with those, you'll get garbage for results.

Comment: oka thanks I'm going to think about another workaround

Answer (score 2):

And over a year later... I needed to do this kind of query with a project where the database can not be normalized for some reason.

This is one possible solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE if(
  instr(myField,'myJsonField'),
  substring(
    substring(myField,instr(myField,'myJsonField')+15),
    1,
    instr(substring(myField,instr(myField,'myJsonField')+15),'\",\"')-1
  ),
  ''
) = 'theJsonValue'
```

Please note that 'myJsonField' has a length of 11, adding to that the symbols of separation of JSON format is 15.