# json data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a mysql table called "Data",

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| data    | text             | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| created | timestamp        | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

The field "data" has values like this:

```
606 | {"first_name":"JOHN","last_name":"SLIFKO","address":"123 main AVE","city":"LAKEWOOD","state":"OH","zip":"20190","home_phone":2165216359,"email":"john@gmail.com",} | 2012-12-04 16:37:23 |
```

So, it is saving the records in a JSON Format from a PHP Script that I have.

THIS IS THE THING:

How can I structure this table to make faster searchs or consults by every single field like doing searches or queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE first_name = john;
```

how can I do this???

Help please......

Comment: Not sure you'll appreciate this comment but.. start by not putting Json data in MySQL... SQL databases are intended to organize data, not to store Json raw data (CouchDB is a Json oriented database, you could use it)

Comment: What Ulflander says. If you want to use mySQL's data structures, indexing, and searching, you'll need to start storing your data accordingly

Comment: Here is the same question, and my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294836/mysql-query-on-json-data/15933396#15933396

Answer (score 1):

Yikes.  Not a good design.  About the best you could do is use the like keyword

```
Select * from Data Where data like '%"first_name":"JOHN"%'
```